# Computer shows error message when being shut down. What does it mean?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003

My OS is Windows XP SP3.

This message sometimes comes up when I am shutting the computer down:

```
The instruction at 0x00000000 referenced memory at 0x00000000.
The memory could not be read.
```

The computer still shuts down. I cannot find a reference to this happening on shutdown, it only seems to be connected to programs that I don't have.

I have the whole Word 2003 package.

Any direction appreciated.

Comment: Basically it means that some process in your box branched to location zero.  This could occur for a number of different reasons, including some software packages that will do this intentionally when they intercept an error they can't handle.  You'd need to find a log entry and maybe a dump of the problem app to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. How can I "dump" the problem app?

Comment: You don't dump the app.  It dumps itself or the system dumps it when it fails.  Or not.  You need to look at the event log to find out what might be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the Event Log (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer). It will contain some error records (marked with red error icon), including application or service name causing the error.

Comment: +1 thanks. I recently added a new printer - the error reads: Source - Brother BRlog - Event 1001. Any further advice?

Comment: Finally figured it out, thanks. I turn off the power on my brother printer when I am not using it and it seems that that is what causes the error when shutting down

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to run a [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) as a first step. I've seen many computers throwing this kind of message when their DRAM modules start to die...

If the memory is OK, then there could be a problem with some application or system components suffering from virus attack. For example Antivirus eliminated a threat, but some binaries were changed by the virus already, and it causes such errors...

Comment: ... the binaries changed by the virus ... makes sense. I recently had a couple of root viruses that I found and removed. Any more direction?

Comment: Then you should reinstall your operating system. Or install new one ontop of the old (Recovery mode), it should fix the files retaining the user's settings...